# Current date in DD-MM-YYYY format in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I get the current date in DD-MM-YYYY format in PostgreSQL? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(now(), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Note:  The result is a string, not a date.  Use standard formats (YYYY-MM-DD) for dates.

Comment: update mst_login set updated_by=p_updatedby,updated_dt = select to_char(now(), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  where license_no=p_licenseno;                                      shows error

Answer (score 0):

To make it this way for entire cluster:

```
set datestyle = SQL,DMY;

select current_date;
 current_date 
--------------
 31/03/2021
```

To persist it change `DateStyle` setting in `postgresql.conf`.

Per information in docs here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT

Comment: where can i find postgresql.conf in postresql

Comment: It is a configuration file and where it is depends on the installation process. It will not be in the database itself, but in some directory.